# keep input text values in form until completion

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form (2nd code box), which when not filled as it should be, gives an error,  and the page is refreshed, thus deleting all the data previously in the form.  What is a possible solution to keep the data in the form, until this is completed and an email is sent?

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST['contact_us'])) {
        $name = $_POST['full_name'];
        $guest_email = $_POST['email_address'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $empty = false;

        function IsInjected($str) {
            $injections = array('(\n+)',
                '(\r+)',
                '(\t+)',
                '(%0A+)',
                '(%0D+)',
                '(%08+)',
                '(%09+)'
            );
            $inject = join('|', $injections);
            $inject = "/$inject/i";
            if (preg_match($inject, $str)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (IsInjected($guest_email)) {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Email")';
            echo '</script>';
        } else if (($name == "FULL NAME") || ($guest_email == "EMAIL ADDRESS")) {
            echo '<div id="overlay">
                    <div id="thank-you">
                        <h6>Missing Information</h6>
                        <p>please fill in the missing information.</p>
                        <button id="close">Close Window</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>';
        } else {
            $email_from = $name; //<== update the email address
            $email_subject = "You have a new message from $name";
            $email_body = "$message \n;" .
                    "Name: $name.\n;" .
                    $to = "email address"; //<== enter personal email here
            $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $guest_email \r\n";
            //Send the email!
            mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
            //done. redirect to thank-you page.
            //header('Location: enquiry.php');

            echo '<div id="overlay">
                    <div id="thank-you">
                        <h6>Thank You</h6>
                        <p>thank you for your enquiry.</br> a reply will be sent via email with 24 hours.</p>
                        <button id="close">Close Window</button>;
                    </div>
                  </div>';

            $name = '';
            $guest_email = '';
            $message = '';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The form

```
<form method="post" name="enquiry-form" action="" target="_self" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" value="FULL NAME"  onFocus="this.value = ''" placeholder="Full Name" />
    <input type="text"  name="email_address" value="EMAIL ADDRESS" onFocus="this.value = ''" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enquiry">Enquiry</textarea>
    <button name="contact_us" type="submit">Submit Enquiry</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the form is on the same php file as the action or is called by the php file you can just include the super global POST values.  Please note your form is missing an action which means it will go to the current page.  Also your inputs have an onFocus action that will cause the value to be deleted on focus (I.e...when you click on the input to edit the value)

```
<form method="post" name="enquiry-form" action="" target="_self" autocomplete="on">
            <input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['full_name'])?>"  onFocus="this.value = ''" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="text"  name="email_address" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email_address'])?>" onFocus="this.value = ''" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enquiry"><?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'])?></textarea>
            <button name="contact_us" type="submit">Submit Enquiry</button>
</form>
```

If the email has been sent, the super global $_POST variable can be cleared:

```
$_POST['full_name'] = null;
$_POST['email_address'] = null;
$_POST['message'] = null;
```

Or you can just flush the entire $_POST variable

```
$_POST = array();
```

Comment: You should be escaping the output, for example `value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['full_name'], ENT_QUOTES) ?>"`. If you don't do this, the form may get corrupted by the user's previous input.

Comment: @rjdown Fixed, thanks forgot about the special characters.

Comment: Thanks .. works pretty well.  How do I clear the fields once the email has been sent?

Comment: @ChriChri Added the instructions to the original answer.  You just need to flush the super globals.

Comment: this method is giving me an undefined index in the form for all values.

Comment: @ChriChri I sounds like you have strict on wich is causing the notices, In this case I'd recommend not flushing the $_POST value using `$_POST = array();`.

Comment: In combination to this - set the variables prior outside of the form processing system, in order to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your input fields on the client side after each key input/field switch via Javascript, which gives you a couple of more options. Then you can us things like: on key up, on blur, when the user sends it, everything should already be sanitized.

this is a good tutorial which shows what I mean https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Check-User-Sign-Up-Name-Ajax-PHP-Social-Network-Tutorial